# Datatables fnDrawCallBack

Tags: pentaho, datatables

I'm using Pentaho which uses Datatables for the Table component. In order to apply some changes to the default dispayed tables I added added this lines of code in the postExectution of my table definition:

```
$('#obj_tabTable').dataTable({"bRetrieve":true}, {
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
        alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
            }
```

But I'm not able to get into the fnDrawCallback, why? The datatable object is instanciated.. Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Datatables does not "officially" support changes like this after initialization, but it is possible. Allan, the creator of datatables, described a method via the internal api [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2737/addchange-callback-after-initialization-or-else-clone-settings-to-re-build-table/p1).

For you it would be:

```
$('#obj_tabTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.push({
    "fn": function () {
        alert("DataTables has redrawn the table");
    },
    "sName": "user"
});
```

Comment: I've already tried your proposed solution but no alert is displayed. The Datatable object is initialized but I'm not able to perform the draw call back function. I neet of it because I want to update my summary row when a word is searched in the SEARCH text box of the table.... Any suggestion? THANKS

Comment: This solution is from the creator of datatables itself and it worked fine on my website. Do you get any javascript errors in this line or any other hint why it is not working for you? Also what versions of jquery and datatables are using?

Comment: I have no error. I'm usign jQuery 1.7.1 and jquery.dataTables.js 1.7.4. thanks

Comment: The thread on the datatables forum I linked is using an even older version 1.7.1. I guess you need to provide more information to find out why it is not working for you.

Comment: I don't know further information to provide you. I'm sure that the table is instantiated by and that I'm able to get into the postExecution function in whihc I located the above lines of code. It could be a behaviour that come out integrating datatables in Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

you can access to the API

Example:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
                var api = this.api();
                var json = api.ajax.json();
                $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                    '<b>$ '+json.anydata+'</b>'
                );

            }
```